# TI SensorTag android app: How to enable accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: android, sensors, iot

I am trying to develop an android app which monitors the TI SensorTag cc2650STK data; accelerometer and gyroscope. I don't know how to enable all the axis (x,y,z) of these sensors. which value I have to write?

```
characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{0x?????});
```

Can anyone explain me with details please?? I found these document from TI but I dont know how to use it:

[CC2650 SensorTag User's Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide)

I am new in android and IoT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank u that was very helpful.....

Answer (score 1):

[This is what I found on GitHub](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/issues/5) regarding your question:

The table on that page describes the bit pattern necessary to enable different parts.

For example: 0x007F should enable all axes on the gyro, accel, and mag. I can't recall the exact byte order (it think it's LE), so your line of code would look like either:

```
characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {(byte)0x7F, (byte)0x00});
```

or

```
characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x7F});
```

EDIT: I Can confirm it's the first option after reviewing TI's User Guide